# Warning after posting text on twitter wall

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter

I am getting the warning,
`Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.` 
after posting the text on twitter wall

hear is the code after this warning is shown

```
ACAccount *acct = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
 TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_textView.text 
                                              forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];
```

hear _textView.text this i am getting the message to post on twitter wall

Why I am getting this warning and how do i get rid of it.

Comment: You can assign this text in NSString as this will be run in background thread so it shows a warning.

Comment: Welcome :) enjoy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show enough code, but probably the response of your request is returned on a background thread and you're directly trying to update the UI. You can't do that. You need to switch back to the main thread once you have received the response and before you update the UI.